# Scrapy : Pass HTTP proxy at runtime

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to set HTTP Proxy for a particular spider in scrapy. Is there a way to pass a HTTP Proxy at runtime in Scrapy?

For example, I can pass user agent during runtime as follows:

```
scrapy crawl <spidername> -s USER_AGENT='<some user agent>'
```

Can I pass the HTTP proxy I want to use in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy understands `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables (see [`HttpProxyMiddleware` documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy))

So you can do something like:

```
http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128" scrapy crawl <spidername>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can pass a proxy at runtime but you could implement a class like this in middleware.py

```
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if spider.name == 'particular_spider':
            proxy = random.choice(LIST_OF_PROXIES)
            request.meta['proxy'] = proxy
```

You could do the same thing with user agent.

```
class CustomUserAgentMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if spider.name =='particular_spider':
            agent = random.choice(USER_AGENTS)
            request.headers['User-Agent'] = agent
```

Just make sure that you add those classes to DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES in settings.py.